# Oracle + C# Cursor trouble

Tags: c#, oracle, powerbuilder

I have the following code in PowerBuilder (with Oracle as the DB)

```
DECLARE lcur_pat_q CURSOR FOR
SELECT HL7_MSG
  FROM HL7_EXPORT_MSG_Q
 WHERE SOCKET_NUM = :al_socket_num
   AND (:as_export_level  = 'C' OR ACCOUNT_NUM = :gv_acctnum)
   AND SUBSTR(HL7_MSG_TYPE, 1, 3) = 'ADT'
ORDER BY HL7_EXPORT_MSG_Q_NUM
FOR UPDATE OF HL7_EXPORT_MSG_Q_NUM;

OPEN lcur_pat_q;
```

How can I rewrite this cursor in C#?

This variant

```
var dbCmd_lcur_pat_q = new OracleCommand();
dbCmd_lcur_pat_q.CommandText = "SELECT HL7_MSG, HL7_EXPORT_MSG_Q_NUM " +
                               "  FROM HL7_EXPORT_MSG_Q " +
                               " WHERE SOCKET_NUM = :al_socket_num " +
                               "   AND (:as_export_level = 'C' OR ACCOUNT_NUM = :gv_acctnum) " +
                               "   AND SUBSTR(HL7_MSG_TYPE, 1, 3) = 'ADT' " +
                               "ORDER BY HL7_EXPORT_MSG_Q_NUM";

dbCmd_lcur_pat_q.Parameters.Add("al_socket_num", OracleDbType.Int32);
dbCmd_lcur_pat_q.Parameters["al_socket_num"].Value = al_socket_num ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
dbCmd_lcur_pat_q.Parameters.Add("as_export_level", OracleDbType.NVarchar2);
dbCmd_lcur_pat_q.Parameters["as_export_level"].Value = as_export_level ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
dbCmd_lcur_pat_q.Parameters.Add("gv_acctnum", OracleDbType.Int32);
dbCmd_lcur_pat_q.Parameters["gv_acctnum"].Value = AppGlobalVariables.gv_acctnum ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
dbCmd_lcur_pat_q.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

var lcur_pat_q = AppGlobalVariables.sqlca.ExecuteReader(dbCmd_lcur_pat_q);
```

returns empty variable lcur_pat_q

The code of ExecuteReader:

```
public OracleDataReader ExecuteReader(OracleCommand command)
{
    try
    {
        if (_connection == null)
            _connection = InitializeConnection();

        if (_transaction == null)
            _transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction();

        command.Connection = _connection;
        command.Transaction = _transaction;

        sqlcode = 0;
        sqlerrtext = String.Empty;
        command.CommandTimeout = 30;
        command.BindByName = true;
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader == null) return null;

        if (!reader.HasRows)
            sqlcode = 100;

        return reader;
    }
    catch (OracleException e)
    {
        sqlcode = e.ErrorCode;
        sqlerrtext = e.Message;
        Debug.Print("{0}: {1}", sqlcode, sqlerrtext);
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        sqlcode = -999;
        sqlerrtext = e.Message;
        Debug.Print("{0}: {1}", sqlcode, sqlerrtext);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to do this and need help.

Comment: what is `AppGlobalVariables.sqlca`?

Comment: it's a Custom DataAccess

Comment: can you show the implementation of `AppGlobalVariables.sqlca.ExecuteReader`?

Comment: Based on the code, it seems very likely that an exception is being thrown, caught, and converted to a `null` return value.  Not the best way to handle exceptions IMO.  At least temporarily, you may want to remove the `catch` blocks so that you can see the exception being thrown.  If that is not enough to help you resolve the problem, please post the full exception message and stack trace.

Comment: Just No Rows are in reader, no exception is being thrown

Comment: In your post, you said: `returns empty variable lcur_pat_q`.  This gave me the impression that you were getting back a `null`, which lead me to believe that an exception was being thrown.  What do you mean by `empty`?  Do you get an `OracleDataReader` instance or is it `null`?  Is it that `HasRows` property returns `false`?  Or is it that when you call `Read()` it returns `false`?

Comment: Not sure if it may help, but as you are using an OracleCommand you could try and use OracleParameters, something like `dbCmd_lcur_pat_q.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter() { ParameterName = "al_socket_num", OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input});`

Comment: I see this is an OLD question, but if this is a cursor there is normally an open, then you do a FETCH for each row found using the cursor. It looks like you are trying to select a result using arguments. I'd look for something similar to FETCH statement.